# difference result when using exslt:node-set with xalan.jar vs rt.jar

Tags: xslt-1.0, xalan, exslt

I have got the difference count of /author/book with the xalan (v.2.7.2) jar file, but I have got the same count with java rt.jar file.

- xalan jar  : ct1=2 and ct2=**0**
- java rt.jar: ct1=2 and ct2=**2**

It looks like the exslt:node-set cannot be used more than one time with the same parameter in the template count for the xalan jar.

I would like to know why I got ct2=0 with the xalan jar, but got ct=2 with java rt.jar?  Is this limitation of xalan.jar or my code is incorrect?

Below is my test xsl.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">    
        <xsl:variable name="mod_books">
            <author>
                <book>book 1</book>
                <book>book 2</book>
            </author>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!--below line gives error org.xml.sax.SAXParseException -->
        <!--print:<xsl:value-of select=$mod_books/author"/><br/>-->        

        <xsl:call-template name="count">                
            <xsl:with-param name="author" select="exslt:node-set($mod_books)" />
        </xsl:call-template>    
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="count">
        <xsl:param name="author" /> 
                ct1=<xsl:value-of select="count(exslt:node-set($author)/author/book)"/> 
            and ct2=<xsl:value-of select="count(exslt:node-set($author)/author/book)"/>
        <br/>

        <!--below line gives error java.lang.ClassCastException if no node-set function in the call template (xsl:with-param name="author" select="$mod_books") -->
        <!--print:<xsl:value-of select=$author/author"/><br/>-->  
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**workaround!**

For the xalan jar, the workaround is to define node-set in a call-template or in a template. These 2 options give the same result (ct1=2 and ct2=2).
Thanks michael.hor257k!

Opt.1

```
<xsl:call-template name="count">                
       <xsl:with-param name="author" select="$mod_books" />
    </xsl:call-template>    
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template name="count">
    <xsl:param name="author" /> 
            ct1=<xsl:value-of select="count(exslt:node-set($author)/author/book)"/> 
        and ct2=<xsl:value-of select="count(exslt:node-set($author)/author/book)"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

Opt.2

```
<xsl:call-template name="count">                
       <xsl:with-param name="author" select="exslt:node-set($mod_books)" />
    </xsl:call-template>    
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="count">
    <xsl:param name="author" /> 
            ct1=<xsl:value-of select="count($author/author/book)"/> 
        and ct2=<xsl:value-of select="count($author/author/book)"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is clearly a bug, but your code makes no sense either: $author is already a node-set - why do you need to apply the node-set() function to it at all?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I have added the node-set function in both location (in call-template with-param and in template param) to avoid exception (ClassCaseException/SAXParseException) if the $mod_books or $author is reached.

Comment: I am talking about $author, not $mod_books. `exslt:node-set($author)` makes no sense, because $author is defined to be a node-set.

Comment: I got your point. This means if $author is defined to be a node-set in the call-template, it cannot be defined the node-set again in the template? Is this xalan jar limitation or bug?

Comment: It's a bug in the sense that you should not get different results for the same code. Other than that, I don't think that the result of calling the node-set() function with a node-set as its argument is formally defined anywhere (keep in mind it's an extension function, not part of the XSLT 1.0 standard). In practice, I think most processors will just return the input - as will yours, the first time it's called.

Comment: Thanks michael.hor257k!